# How to use one model property in another view model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have 2 model classes contactdetails.cs and empmodel.cs
I have a view called empdetails.cshtml and the model i am using for this page is empmodel.cs.
I want to use a property Mobile from contactdetails.cs

Can I use like this in mvc?

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.contactdetails.Mobile)
```

Comment: Does EmpModel have a ContactDetails property?

Comment: I have no idea as I am new to this environment. Should I write like this empmodel.cs?? public string ContactDetails{get; set;}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Since you are using `empmodel` for this view you cannot do it.

What you can you do is create a `ViewModel` with with `contactdetails` and `empmodel` and use that `ViewModel` in your view.

e.g.

```
public class EmpViewModel
{
    public EmpModel Empmodel { get; set; }
    public ContactDetails contactdetails { get; set; }
}
```

And in your view `empdetails.cshtml` you can use it as follow;

```
@model EmpViewModel

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.contactdetails.Mobile)
```